# Jquery Datatable: Object doesn't support property or method 'Draw' asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, datatable

using the following code:

HTML:

```
  <head runat="server">
    <title>datatable loading searching, sorting and updating </title>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scroller.dataTables.min.css" />

 <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function () {
                  BindCompanyTable();
                    //Adding  Data manually to datatable
                  appendCompanyData()
              // this is for document ready
               });


         function BindCompanyTable() {

                    myTable = $("#tblCompany").DataTable({
                        "deferRender": true,
                        "paging": true,
                        "lengthChange": false,
                        "searching": true,
                        "ordering": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "autoWidth": false,
                        "sDom": 'lfrtip'
                        //"sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"
                    });
                }

          function appendCompanyData() {
                  alert('inside appendCompanyData');
                    //'DATA SHOWING'
                    var companytable = $('#tblCompany tbody');
                    companytable.append('<tr><td>1 </td><td> CompanyA</td><td>Bryant</td></tr>'); 
                    companytable.append('<tr><td>2 </td><td> CompanyB</td><td>Little Rock</td></tr>'); 
                    companytable.append('<tr><td>3 </td><td> CompanyC</td><td>Little Rock</td></tr>'); 
                    companytable.append('<tr><td>4 </td><td> CompanyD</td><td>Little Rock</td></tr>'); 
                    companytable.append('<tr><td>5 </td><td> CompanyE</td><td>Little Rock</td></tr>'); 

        //this line is giving an error
        //Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Draw'

                    companytable.Draw();

 }

   </script>

</head >



   <table id="tblCompany"  border="1" style="border-collapse:">
     <thead>
        <tr>
        <th id="thcompany">CompanyRecordID</th>
        <th>CompanyName</th>
        <th>City</th>                       
         </tr>
        </thead>                
      <tbody></tbody>
     </table>
```

Displaying 5 rows using jquery Datatable and I want to check how search and ordering works with datatable. The data shows up on the form but I get the error above on this line of code:

```
companytable.Draw();
```

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Draw'

Also,as I type a keyword in search input box, the 5 data rows  disappears and I see this: "No data available in table"  showing inside data table.

the Data table column header are showing OK

Am I missing a Jquery plug in or may not adding the correct Plug in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the following line of code:

var ctable = new $.fn.dataTable.Api('#tblCompany');
ctable.draw();

Also the %> at the end of src attribute in script tags was left my mistake because the line of code was copied from another line of code with this syntax.

" type="text/javascript">

then later I removed the ResolveUrl
Just a typing error

Comment: I am not sure how your answer is different from the one provided above. `$('tblCompany').draw()` should do the trick as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `draw` method on table tbody instead of table

```
var companytable = $('#tblCompany tbody');
```

Instead, you should be calling it on tblCompany element like this:

```
$('tblCompany').draw()
```

Also, I am not sure why you have `%>` at the end of src attribute in script tags

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```